# vim colorscheme shows wrong color

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I want to change my colorscheme to this: `earthsong` on `http://daylerees.github.io/`

but it changes color something srange. like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0CwE.jpg) (up: molokai, down: earthsong)

I try `:colorscheme earthsong` in vim, it gives same result.

I using vim on mac (latest version)

I got .vim code from `https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes/blob/master/vim/colors/earthsong.vim`

Can I get some help?

Answer (score 6):

1. The very first place to look for help with an open source project is [its issue tracker](https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes/issues) if it exists.
2. That colorscheme only uses your terminal palette. This means that you must adjust it to the colors used in the colorscheme which don't seem to be listed anywhere else than in the colorscheme itself.

If you use Vim 8 and an up-to-date iTerm you could tell Vim to use your GUI colors in the terminal with:

```
set termguicolors
```